# Django one-to-many form issue with form

Tags: python, django

I have created a one-to-many relationship model and a form. The issue is when i load the form it just lists the models name + 'object' not list the actual data in the field. So if i have a Locations class with 10 locations. In the person form i get a dropdown box with 'Location object' inside not a list of locations.

models.py

```
class Location(models.Model):
    location_name = models.CharField()
    ect

class Person(models.Model):
    location = models.ForeignKey(Location)
    name = models.CharField()
```

form.py

class LocationForm(forms.ModelForm):

```
class Meta:
    model = Location
```

class PersonForm(forms.ModelForm):

```
class Meta:
    model = Person
```

.html

```
<form action="/persons/get/person/create/" method="post" role="form">{% csrf_token %}
            {{form.as_p}} 
    <input type="submit" name="submit" value="Create person">
    </form>
```

Answer (score 3, accepted):

You need to declare the [`__unicode__` method](https://docs.djangoproject.com/en/dev/ref/models/instances/#unicode) on the model.

```
class Location(models.Model):
    location_name = models.CharField()

    def __unicode__(self): #or __str__ for python 3.x
        return u'%s' % self.location_name #Or whatever field

class Person(models.Model):
    location = models.ForeignKey(Location)
    name = models.CharField()


    def __unicode__(self): #or __str__ for python 3.x
        return u'%s' % self.name #or whatever field
```

Make sure you use [`__str__` if you use python 3.x](https://docs.djangoproject.com/en/dev/ref/models/instances/#str)